# Determining when smarty created a cache file

Tags: php, smarty

I've got a cms, each page stores the time that it was last updated in a database. I've got caching set up in smarty (3.1), but I want to be able to clear the cache and force it to create a new cache file if the page was updated since the last saved cache file, but to do that I need to know when the cached file was created.

Is there a way of getting the timestamp of the cached file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently answered a similar question: [Smarty cache site properties in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714946/smarty-cache-site-properties-in-database/7715302#7715302)

```
<?php
// fill these if you do cache grouping and or have different compiles of the same template
$template = 'foobar.tpl';
$cache_id = null;
$compile_id = null;

$smarty = new Smarty();
$tpl = $smarty->createTemplate($template, $cache_id, $compile_id);
if ($tpl->isCached() && $tpl->cached->timestamp < $yourTimestampFromDB) {
  $smarty->clearCache($template, $cache_id, $compile_id);
}
```

Comment: Right! Didn't think of that; I was thinking of an `->getTimestamp()`. `:s`

Comment: Not that creating a class to encapsulate the OP's functionality would be a bad thing... `:P`

Comment: Smarty_CacheResource::getTimestamp() is meant to fetch the modified time of a cache object from your storage (file, db, whatever). It could however very well check that mtime against some other database table and return false if the cache has been outdated. Have a look at demo/cacheresource.mysqls.php :)

Comment: Smarty 3.1.4 will probably hit it next week. Then Custom CacheResources will also automatically benefit from cache locking (amongst other things)

Comment: I'm not sure where you're pointing to ([here?](http://smarty-php.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distribution/demo/plugins/resource.mysqls.php)). So is what you're saying that currently `Smarty_CacheResource` may report an out of date timestamp due to some kind of race condition? (Note, I'm not doubting you're right, just trying to understand what you're saying.)

Comment: [Smarty_CacheResource_Mysql](http://smarty-php.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distribution/demo/plugins/cacheresource.mysql.php) is the one I'm talking about. Not a real race condition problem, but have a look at [$cache_locking](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.cache.locking.tpl) :)

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. I think I also initially misunderstood your first comment (if you were suggesting that that would be a way of doing it, as well as a demonstration).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Smarty has anything internal for this. But look at [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/filemtime) and [`filectime`](http://php.net/filectime) for determining when a file was last modified and changed respectively.

From php.net:

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last changed: " . date("F d Y H:i:s.", filectime($filename));
}
```

Difference between modified-time and change-time:

> Note: In most Unix filesystems, a file is considered changed when its inode data is changed; that is, when the permissions, owner, group, or other metadata from the inode is updated. See also filemtime() (which is what you want to use when you want to create "Last Modified" footers on web pages) and fileatime().

Comment: Thanks, I was really hoping there was something internal (I sure can't find it though) as manually calculating the cached file name and checking that seemed like it would just lead to problems if they changed how the file names were generated.

Comment: @Al_ Give it some time. Maybe someone else around here knows more about Smarty internals than I do :)

Comment: @Al_ - Actually, probably what you would want to do is extend the [`Smarty_CacheResource_Custom`](http://smarty-php.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distribution/libs/sysplugins/smarty_cacheresource_custom.php) class, which contains a method for `fetchTimestamp()` it inherits from [`Smarty_CacheResource`](http://smarty-php.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distribution/libs/sysplugins/smarty_cacheresource.php).

Comment: @JaredFarris Smarty 3.1 gives you total access to all information you could possibly need. It just doesn't mention that in the docs.